# Can I spoof the MAC address in Android?

Tags: networking, wifi, android, wpa-supplicant, spoofing

Is it possible to spoof the MAC address of the wireless interface using  `wpa_supplicant.conf` in Android when I connect as a client to an access point?

**Edit**
Unfortunately, Android doesn't support

```
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I've been using

```
ip link set eth0 address 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

but that only works temporarily. After I disconnect and reconnect to the access point, the mac resets itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, `wpa_supplicant` cannot change interface's MAC address. But if you have root shell on your Android you can try to change MAC address with `ifconfig`.

Comment: thanks, I've tried that but unfortunately it doesnt work.